# How can I use useState Reactjs to control open or close a Modal Bootstrap? (not use ReactBootstrap library)

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I am working with Bootstrap modal and Reactjs. Now I want to control how to open and close a Bootstrap Modal without Jquery code. So my idea is using useState to control state of modal, if true it will add class "show" to open modal and false it add class "hide". But it not work, How can I solve this? Or are there anyway to control modal without Jquery code? Thanks

```
const [openModal, setopenModal] = useState(false);
const openmodal = () => {
   setopenModal(!openModal);
};
return (
 <div>
  <button onClick={openmodal}>open</button>
   <div id="mod" className={`modal ${openModal ? 'show' : 'hide'}`}>
    <div className="modal-dialog modal-xl">
      <div className="modal-content">
        hello
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the data attributes.

> Options can be passed via data attributes or JavaScript. For data
>   attributes, append the option name to data-, as in data-show="".

The data-show attribute specifies whether to show the modal when initialized.

```
<div id="mod" data-show={openModal ? 'true' : 'false'}> ... </div>
```

See: https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_modal.asp

Alternatively you could use useRef to get the modal DOM element and access it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function model(){
  const [openModal, setopenModal] = useState(false);

  const openmodal = () => {
     setopenModal(state=>!state);
  };

  return (
     <div>
       <button onClick={openmodal}>open</button>
       <div id="mod" className={`modal ${openModal ? 'show' : 'hide'}`}>
        <div className="modal-dialog modal-xl">
          <div className="modal-content">
            hello
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help, @Abdur. But it does not work, modal is not displayed by adding class "show" or "hide".